# Error npm install --save @angular/fire@5.1.1 firebase@5.8.4 gyp ERR! build error

Tags: angular, firebase

I am writing my first firebase and find the install process difficult. I tried the following command

npm install --save @angular/fire@5.1.1 firebase@5.8.4

the cmd with admin, cited no python found

In installed the following

npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

npm install --gloabl node-gyp

it took several times before it finally completed

When I ran the firebase install command again, it gave me the following error.

I read many stack posts, I have been repeating the same install steps again but no success.
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=D:\\Projects\\Marvelocity\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=D:\\Projects\\Marvelocity\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=6" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v83"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\Projects\Marvelocity\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v14.3.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=D:\Projects\Marvelocity\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=D:\Projects\Marvelocity\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\Marvelocity\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1051:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "D:\\Projects\\Marvelocity\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd D:\Projects\Marvelocity\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v14.3.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=D:\Projects\Marvelocity\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=D:\Projects\Marvelocity\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v83-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=6 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v83' (1)
npm WARN codelyzer@5.2.1 requires a peer of tslint@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/fire@5.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/common@>=6.0.0 <8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/fire@5.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0 <8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/fire@5.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@>=6.0.0 <8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/fire@5.1.1 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@>=6.0.0 <8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/fire@5.1.1 requires a peer of zone.js@^0.8.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.18.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.18.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-11T17_13_16_147Z-debug.log
```

Comment: In the install log there is node version `14.3.0` installed. Node `14.x.x` has `NODE_MODULE_VERSION` `83`. If we take a look at the response of https://node-precompiled-binaries.grpc.io/ of `grpc`we are able to see, that there is no prebuilt library for Node module version `83`. The latest supported Node module version is `51` which means Node version `7.x.x`. Since its quite old, the local build remains the only option. I tried to build it locally like you, but unfortunately I did not succeed with Node LTS version (`12.x.x`).